# How to integrate zoho crm webforms(Ex:Contact us) in Reactjs PWA application

Tags: reactjs, zoho

I have a generated Zoho CRM webform for Contact us. I need to integrate that form into my react application and submit user inputs. I can get the iframe version, javascript version, and HTML/CSS version of the generated code. I want to know which one is best for the Reactjs PWA application and can we use this directly with react. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You've asked many questions at once, separate it by numbered list.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding `iframe` altogether. You might find a lot of issues when dealing with cross-domain artifacts and policies. If you want to customize the look and feel of the form, better go ahead with the `HTML & CSS` version. `JavaScript` file will be an external dependency. It also would be a hacky / non-react way.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish, I alerdy used HTML/css version.but seems like form data not submitted to crm eventhough my form submit is success. I have customized submit function and added some formdata as hidden fields value.

Comment: Could you post a minimal jsfiddle/code sandbox that i can look into?

Comment: Thanks @ashish for advice. I checked with zoho crm community and they suggested to go with zoho APIs when integrating zoho crm with third party libraries.